# How to apply css properties on all sub routes dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, laravel

I am creating menu sidebar in laravel php so i want to apply some css dynamically at all sub url's 
ie.

suppose there are some url's

1. electronics/tv/panasonic/xxmodeltv
2. electronics/computers/laptop/hp/hp 15-r001ne
3. electronics/xyz/xyx/sd
4. electronics/mobiles/android/nokia/nokia5

so i want to apply some css on all sub categories of electronics/* links so tell me that how to ignore all sub url's of electronics.

I have a sidebar menu and

there are i am using if condition with or"||" for every sub url's

```
<?php  $url = Request::path(); ?>

@if($url == 'electronic' || $url == 'electronics/mobiles' || $url == 'electronics/computers' || $url == 'electronics/tv) 
 class="active"
@endif
```

i want to do short this complex code

```
<div class="list-group" >
         <a  class="list-group-item active" style="border-radius: 0px; color: #0e0d0d;">
           {{ Auth::user()->name }}
         </a>

         <a href="{{ url('admin/') }}" class="list-group-item" <?php if ($url == 'admin') { echo ' style="    background-color: #f7f7f7; border-left: 6px orange solid;"'; } ?>>
            <i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
            Dashboard
         </a>
         <a href="{{ url('admin/profile') }}" class="list-group-item" <?php if ($url == 'admin/profile' || $url == 'admin/profile/user' || $url == 'admin/profile/view' || $url == 'admin/profile/create') { echo ' style="    background-color: #f7f7f7; border-left: 6px orange solid;"'; } ?>><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> profile</a>
         <a href="{{ url('admin/file_manager') }}" class="list-group-item" <?php if ($url == 'admin/file_manager') { echo ' style="    background-color: #f7f7f7; border-left: 6px orange solid;"'; } ?>><i class="fa fa-file" aria-hidden="true"></i> File Manager</a>
         <a href="{{ url('admin/enquries') }}" class="list-group-item" <?php if ($url == 'admin/enquries') { echo ' style="background-color: #f7f7f7; border-left: 6px orange solid;"'; } ?>><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i> Enquiries</a>

         <a href="{{ url('admin/tourpack') }}" class="list-group-item" <?php if ($url == 'admin/tourpack' || $url == 'admin/tourpack/create' || $url == 'admin/tourpack/edit' || $url == admin/tourpack/view' ) { echo ' style="    background-color: #f7f7f7; border-left: 6px orange solid;"'; } ?>><i class="fa fa-cube" aria-hidden="true"></i> Tour Packages</a>

         <a href="{{ url('admin/travel_guide') }}" class="list-group-item" <?php if ($url == 'admin/travel_guide' || $url == 'admin/travel_guide/create'|| $url == 'admin/travel_guide/view'|| $url == 'admin/travel_guide/edit') { echo ' style="    background-color: #f7f7f7; border-left: 6px orange solid;"'; } ?>>Tour Guidlines</a>

         <a href="{{ url('admin/transport') }}" class="list-group-item" <?php if ($url == 'admin/transport' || $url == 'admin/transport/create'$url == 'admin/transport/view'$url == 'admin/transport/edit') { echo ' style="    background-color: #f7f7f7; border-left: 6px orange solid;"'; } ?>><i class="fa fa-car" aria-hidden="true"></i> Transport's</a>

         <a href="{{ url('admin/states') }}" class="list-group-item" <?php if ($url == 'admin/states') { echo ' style="    background-color: #f7f7f7; border-left: 6px orange solid;"'; } ?>>States</a>
         <a href="{{ url('admin/countries') }}" class="list-group-item" <?php if ($url == 'admin/countries') { echo ' style="    background-color: #f7f7f7; border-left: 6px orange solid;"'; } ?>>Countries</a>

         <a href="{{ url('admin/settings') }}" class="list-group-item" <?php if ($url == 'admin/settings' || $url == 'admin/settings/contacts') { echo ' style="background-color: #f7f7f7; border-left: 6px orange solid;"'; } ?>><i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            Settings</a>

        </div>
```

Comment: What result are you expecting

Comment: The url(s) you mentioned can not have css, we need to apply css to `<li>` or whatever html tags you have used to create menu, so you must show the code to get help.

Comment: okay  i am uploading code

Comment: it can be accomplished through jQuery .. for php you have to write quite alot of code

Comment: if you want i can make a fiddle for you.. just in case someone else is looking for that kind of logic too

Comment: off-course i want please suggest me that how to use jquery for this..

Comment: if you find it according to your need please accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

here is the just readymade code for you hope you will find it helpfull

```js
  $(function () {
    var textToBeFind = 'electronics';
    $(".list-group a").each(function () {
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      (href.indexOf(textToBeFind) != -1)?  $(this).addClass('someClass'):'';
    });
  });
```

```css
a {
    display: block;
  }
  .someClass{
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="electronics/tv/panasonic/xxmodeltv">link</a>
  <a href="electronics/mobiles/android/nokia/123">link</a>
  <a href="electronics/mobiles/android/nokia/123">link</a>
  <a href="electronics/mobiles/android/nokia/123">link</a>
  <a href="electronics/mobiles/android/nokia/123">link</a>
  <a href="electronics/mobiles/android/nokia/123">link</a>
  <a href="electronics/mobiles/android/nokia/123">link</a>
  <a href="bikes/#">link</a>
  <a href="mobiles/#">link</a>
  <a href="others/#">link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks It is very halpfull for me.

Comment: accept the answer like in the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in plain CSS, it is exactly what CSS is supposed to accomplish.

In your view (controller would be better, keep code out of views)

```
<?php $section = request()->segment(2); // 'profile', 'settings', etc ?>
```

In your view:

```
<!-- Add your new section identifier here -->
<div class="list-group {{ $section }}">
    ...
    <!-- Remove inline CSS -->
    <a href="{{ url('admin/') }}" class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Dashboard</a>
    <a href="{{ url('admin/profile') }}" class="list-group-item" ><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> profile</a>
    <a href="{{ url('admin/file_manager') }}" class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-file" aria-hidden="true"></i> File Manager</a>
    ...
</div>
```

In your CSS file:

```
/* This applies to everything, unless overridden */
.list-group .list-group-item {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-left: 6px orange solid;
}

/* Now you can override just the cases you want, eg different style for profiles */
.list-group.profile .list-group-item {
    background-color: #000000;
    border-left: 6px white solid;
    color: white;
}

/* Another different style for some other site section */
.list-group.file_manager .list-group-item {
    background-color: #white;
    border-left: 6px black solid;
    color: black;
}
```